# How to access Hyper-V in Windows 8 Pro

Tags: windows-8, virtualization, hyper-v

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use Windows Virtual PC in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/472499/how-do-i-install-and-use-windows-virtual-pc-in-windows-8)

According to [this blog post](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/bloggingwindows/archive/2012/04/16/announcing-the-windows-8-editions.aspx) and various other sources on the internet, the 'Pro' version of Windows 8 includes Microsoft [Hyper-V virtualisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V), but I when I search for it in the Start Screen I get no results.

Comment: Enable it under Windows Features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyper-V is included with Windows 8 Pro but not enabled by default on a fresh install.

It is an optional Windows feature that you need to enable manually:

1. Press Win + R to launch the run box
2. Type OptionalFeatures.exe and press Enter
3. Check Hyper-V and click OK to enable the feature.
4. Launch the Start Screen and search, 'Hyper-V Manager' should now be
   available.

Note: **Hyper-V is not available if you are running Windows 8 in a virtual machine.** i.e. 'Nested virtualisation' is not supported.