# Use Windows XP Mode in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-xp-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use Windows Virtual PC in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/472499/how-do-i-install-and-use-windows-virtual-pc-in-windows-8)

Can anyone tell me where can I get Windows XP mode to use in Windows 8? I still have many legacy apps that don't support Windows 8.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how *Run in Compatibility* mode works but have you tried Right Click on the program -> Properties -> Compatibility tab -> Run in Windows XP compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a free awesome tool : [VMLite XP Mode](http://www.vmlite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=47&Itemid=143)

It works in Windows 8 without requiring any valid licenses or hardware acceleration (VT-x / AMD-V).

Comment: So how do you run XP in a VM without a license legally?

Comment: I think VMLite XP Mode implements some trick which doesn't allow Windows to ask for any product key or show the activation window.

Comment: That sounds a bit shady and possibly illegal

Answer (score 6):

XP mode no longer exists -

> Windows 8 does not include XP mode, a function of Windows Virtual PC. Virtual PC itself got the axe in Windows 8 in favor of a set of new features and preferred software platform.

[Source](http://www.lockergnome.com/news/2012/09/06/windows-8-xp-mode/)

So you'll need to install some other virtual machine software and install XP in that instead. You will need a valid XP license though, so if you upgraded your XP license to get to Windows 7 you'll be out of luck.

Comment: Where do i get a valid license? I think nobody sells them now.

Comment: @Root - I've no idea, sorry.

Comment: @Root XP Mode gives you a free XP Professional licence, provided you have a valid Windows 7 Professional/Enterprise/Ultimate licence. You should be able to install XP in your VM solution of choice (Hyper-V, VMWare, VirtualBox or whatever), you just have to grab the product key from the XP Mode VHD.

Answer (score 2):

'Windows XP' - mode was an instance of 'Virtual PC', which is replaced in Windows-8 by 'Hyper-V'. You can create a new virtual machine running Windows XP in such a machine (just as you could run it inside VirtualBox or VMware etc).

Comment: One could even load the same VHD file.