# Using OEM disks to install Windows 7 partition on Windows 8 laptop

Tags: partitioning, windows-installation

I own a Toshiba Satellite laptop that originally came with Windows 7 on it.  I currently have Windows 8 installed only (no other OSs on other partitions).  I am a software developer and would like to test my app on Windows 7.  So I'd like to reintroduce a Windows 7 partition without disturbing the present Windows 8 partition.

The Toshiba-provided disks I have are System Recovery disks, Windows Recovery Environment, and Applications & Drivers.  I read about "recovery" in the computer's manual, but it just mentions wiping the 'C' drive and then restoring it to the "out of box" state.  This is definitely not what I want.  I want to create a new partition that has Windows 7 on it while leaving the present Windows 8 partition alone.  Please advise me how to accomplish this.

Comment: You persist on using real hw or virtual machine will suffice?

Comment: I had thought (hoped) that they had stopped doing that - wiping the entire disk. It has been a long time since I saw it. Can you try on another PC and see what it does? If it does, then what about the Windows 8 install? Does that format the entire drive? If not, back up up your data, install 7 (formtatting the entire drive), create a new parition and install 8 to that. Or just buy a second PC? If you want to develop for the touchscreen aspects of 8 you will porbably have to buy a new device anyway in order to test.

Answer (score 2):

What you will most likely have to do, if the restore disk is your only available method of installing Windows 7, is to go through with the restore. This **WILL** wipe the HDD and any data on it.

Once the system is back to factory, shrink and do what ever else you need/want to do with your partitions and install Windows 8 on it's own partition.

*n.b. this is assuming you actually have a full install of Windows 8 and not just an upgrade.*

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't answer my question since I do not want to disturb the Windows 8 partition.  If wiping turns out to be necessary, then I'd instead prefer buying a cheap Windows 7 machine to test on.

Comment: You could always just buy a Windows 7 DVD of what ever edition is sufficient for your needs and install that on a second partition, or better yet inside a Virtual Machine.

Comment: This article seems to provide an alternative to buying the DVD: http://www.pcworld.com/article/248995/how_to_install_windows_7_without_the_disc.html

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to restore your Windows 7 installation and then use [Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) or a number of [other methods](http://www.interactivewebs.com/blog/index.php/server-tips/converting-a-physical-windows-machine-to-a-hyper-v-virtual-machine-p2v-problem/) to convert a physical machine into a Hyper-V, VMware or other virtual machine.

You can then install Windows 8 without the Windows 7 partition. You can run your Windows 7 VM using Windows 8's [built in Hyper-V](https://superuser.com/questions/472499/how-do-i-install-and-use-windows-virtual-pc-in-windows-8) or [boot directly](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825689.aspx) into the VHD.