# How to install Windows 7 alongside Windows 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, installation, multi-boot

I bought a new laptop (HP 4540s) and also a Windows 8 DVD. I installed Windows 8 but it's not user friendly. Now I want to install Windows 7 on the same laptop while keeping Windows 8 also (multiboot) because this is a company laptop and it does not want me to remove Windows 8.

How I can install Windows 7 alongside Windows 8 please?

I have Windows 7 Pro original DVD including product key.
Note : This laptop is DOS base.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of dual booting, you can [install Hyper-V on Windows 8](https://superuser.com/a/472500/144961), and then use Windows 7 as a virtual machine within Windows 8. This would let you use both operating systems at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

[Lifehacker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifehacker) has a pretty good article about this, *[How to Dual-Boot Windows 7 and Windows 8 Side By Side](http://lifehacker.com/5840387/how-to-dual+boot-windows-7-and-windows-8-side-by-side)*.

Comment: Please include a basic summary of how to do it, if that link ever goes down your answer will provide no helpful information for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a way to get it working, Windows 7 ever has problems, or you still haven't successfully installed it, then there is [Skip Metro Suite](http://winaero.com/download.php?view.33).

It installs a start menu with some options, including a couple of toolbar options and the option to skip the [Metro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_%28design_language%29) welcome screen - which makes it easier to use Windows 8 (perhaps that's why you chose to use Windows 7)?